# MAC HomeBrew getting errors

Tags: macos, homebrew

(I'm using a MAC with High Sierra 10.13.10)

HomeBrew isn't working.  I get errors trying to use it.
For example:

```
$ brew --version
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you done the `xcode-select --install` thing in Terminal since your last macOS upgrade?

Comment: Mark - I ran that command and I still get the same error.

Comment: And `brew doctor`

Comment: brew doctor give me the same error

Comment: Has **homebrew** previously worked on this machine or have you just installed it?

Comment: Homebrew was working on this MAC.  But, it's been over a year since I used it.

Comment: Can I uninstall and install Homebrew or will that break any software I installed using it?

Comment: Not sure what to advise. Personally, I would make a backup. Then rename `/usr/local/bin` to `/usr/local/bin.old` and likewise `/usr/local/Cellar` to `/usr/local/Cellar.old`. Then reinstall **homebrew**. But I would also wait 24 hours to see if anyone smarter than me had a better idea!